# How to reset IIS Authentication Settings

Tags: authentication, iis, windows-authentication

0

I have Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication both enabled for my website. My website is called "myapp".

My problem is, I used to be able to navigate to my website fine i.e: "https://www.myapp.com" but now everytime I go to "https://www.myapp.com" I get a signin popup.

What I have done was removed "myapp" and renamed it to "myapps" then converted it to an application on IIS again and it worked the way it was before without the signin popup.

Somehow, IIS still remembers the settings I had previously and I couldn't change it back.

I've tried:
- recycle app pool with new settings
- stop and start app pool
- switching to app pool that is working
- delete and re-create app pool
- delete the app and re-publish
- various web.config settings - which I don't think necessary because I could  publish the same app with a different name and it'll work as I expected.
- reboot IIS
- reboot Azure Server

Comment: I found  you add the azure web site tag. Do you host the web application on the azure web app service? As far as I know the azure web app doesn't contains the windows auth, it contains Azure AD auth. If you want to enable or disable th AAD autg in the azure web app, I suggest you could try to use azure web app service setting to achieve your requirement. Details, you could refer to below [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).

Comment: I am hosting it on Azure and it didn't behave like this before. I actually have 2 other apps going plus the one I've just created with a different name. I want the name back but every time I go to the website the login popup shows up.

Comment: I suggest you could try to change a browser and clear the browser  to access the web sites. Could you please post the authentication setting image for your web sites? Besides,I suggest you could try to disable the windows auth and try to access the sites again to make sure the auth setting is working well or not.